# How to use a TL431 for PMOS based reverse polarity protection?

Tags: tl431

Consider the following illustration:
[image: pmos based reverse polarity protection]

I wonder if it possible to replace the zener with a TL431. The usual application of TL431 supplies specific voltage to next stage but the zener here supplies voltage Vin - Vz to turn the pmos on.

Comment: What is the maximum Vin? If the Vgs max of the FET is larger than Vin, you can directly connect the gate to GND.

Comment: The Vin of the circuit to protect is 9-24v, and the Vgs of pmos is 10v, so I have to regulate Vin so it will not kill the pmos.

Comment: Makes sense. Hopefully you mean the max recommended Vgs. It would not be a good idea to use a 10V Zener if the absolute max Vgs is 10V. But most FET's have an absolute max higher than that, so most likely it is OK. If any doubt, add the FET p/n to your question.

Answer (score 2):

10V zeners are quite nice devices for this application - quite sharp knee and far more accurate than required, not to mention cheap (only one part vs 3), and easily available. I can't imagine you would more than a couple types for any practical range of MOSFETs. Usually Vgs(max) is 20V, 10V or 8V, and usually the 8V types cannot handle your upper range of voltage.

You **can** likely use a TL431 with a couple resistors, but I would suggest a Zener diode in most cases. The TL431 is an active circuit- it has this characteristic below the minimum current for regulation (the below graph is typical, worst case Imin is 2.5x higher- 1ma):

[image]

The low current behavior of a 10V zener is far less non-ideal. For example, this nice SMT zener family ([MM3ZxxxST1G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MM3Z2V4ST1-D.PDF)):

[image]

Even at a few uA they are behaving reasonably.

The other "interesting" characteristic is the "tunnel of death" stability range:

[image]

The MOSFET gate represents a capacitive load on the TL431 shunt regulator. Especially if you choose to use it at lower voltages than 10V you could run into stability issues at the edges with some MOSFETs at some temperatures. You cannot make a Zener diode oscillate, at least not so as you would notice it in this circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to replace a cheap fast robust zener with a slower, more expensive TL431?

You can. A 431 can be configured with two resistors to clamp voltage more accurately than a zener, especially at lower currents. But with more components, there's more to go wrong.

Here, you don't need that accuracy, and simplicity says use a zener.

Comment: Because Vgs can be different if different pmos is used. For fully driving the pmos I choose, I have to purchase zener with different Vz. I can just purchase TL431 and program them for all pmos if zener here can be replaced.

Comment: No, you buy one zener voltage, slightly lower than the max gate voltage, usually +/- 20v, so any zener in the 10v/15v ballpark will do for almost any PMOS.

Comment: I am skeptical. I think a 10V Zener will work for almost any PMOS you can find. 10V is enough to turn on just about any PMOS out there, and only a very few PMOS have a Vgs max lower than 12V. Furthermore, from a BOM management perspective, it is no more trouble to choose a different Zener than it is to choose a different resistor value to program the TL431.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit is designed for reverse polarity protection .The Zener is present to protect the gate of the Pmos fet .As long as the zener starts working before the Vgs rating is exceeded then it is fine .There is no point in using a more accurate and in this case more tempermental device .If you must still do this you could use say a 10K and a 30K resistor to program the TL431 to 10Volts .